# IPv6 & Linux tools

Tags: networking, dns, home-networking, ipv6

I got a new internet plan from my ISP and was doing the `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` thing. So I noticed that the addresses that `apt` was fetching were all IPv6 addresses. Not only `apt`, but other tools as well. Such as `ssh` and `wget`.

Strangely enough, my ISP does not support IPv6. So I guessed that, although it was fetching IPv6 addresses, it was fallbacking into IPv4 (since the time spent when forcing the use of IPv4 was way shorter).

I also think that even though my ISP does not support IPv6, the modem (in fact, I don't even know if this is possible) is encapsulating the IPv4 DNS requests into IPv6 (or something like this). And that would be sort of an explanation to the reason of the programs mentioned choosing IPv6.

One example with `wget` (note that both  `apt` and `ssh` both have the same behavior):

`$ wget google.com` -> [output](https://pastebin.com/Fj9VChrY)

`$ wget -4 google.com` -> [output](https://pastebin.com/0ZMwsDSj)

Besides the fact that I have a shitty DNS server, it's possible to see `wget` trying to connect via IPv6, giving up and finally fallbacking to IPv4.

I strongly believe that I'm wrong. So, how does it all really work? Is it because I have a local IPv6 address? Btw, is the modem or the SO the one who chooses if I will have an IPv6 local address? Does it matter having one?

I'm just too confused!!

Comment: What addresses _do_ you have? That is, what does `ip addr` show?

Comment: The wlan section (which matters here) is something like [this](https://pastebin.com/mmyXcGvm).

Comment: Well, that `2804:14c:5b8f:29:…` very much looks like a [global](http://bgp.he.net/ip/2804:14c:5b8f:29::), ISP-assigned address. Maybe they're in the middle of a half-assed rollout? Or your router isn't configured properly and _could_ do IPv6 but its firewall is blocking it?

Comment: Wouldn't that be something like a local address like the `192.168.0.15`? But if that (half-assed rollout), it means that it is tricking the programs into thinking they can use IPv6!?

Comment: No, it's not a local address.

Comment: What do your router settings say about IPv6?

Comment: Oh, didn't saw the link... Well, that explains my confusion... So, summarizing, I actually have an IPv6, but can't use it (I've just tried to turn all my firewalls down, and didn't change anything). Thanks, @grawity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your pastebin, you *do* have a global, ISP-assigned IPv6 address. The prefix `2804:14c:5b8f:29:...` belongs to – not sure whether "Grupo de Segurança Vírtua" or "CLARO S.A" is the right one? Regardless, it's a valid global address.

So the problem is that your ISP (or perhaps your router) is providing you with addresses but not with actual IPv6 connectivity. Like in the comments – it could be that the ISP is rolling out IPv6 from the wrong end, or that your router's firewall blocks IPv6 packets. I would suggest calling your ISP's tech support.

---

Regarding IPv6 address assignment: Normally in IPv6 each customer gets an *entire subnet* (prefix) from the ISP, and each device can have its own global address in that subnet. (The whole point of IPv6 is that the vast amount of available addresses makes things like "192.168" *unnecessary*.)

So in this case, your router has obtained the `2804:14c:5b8f:29::/64` prefix from your ISP (usually via DHCPv6-PD), and is advertising it on the LAN as "auto-configurable". This is normal behavior.

(Roughly speaking, if the 1st chunk is in the `2000`–`5fff` range then it's global, while `f000`–`ffff` covers most kinds of local addresses.)

---

Regarding DNS, what a request *asks for* has absolutely nothing to do with how it is *delivered* – a client can perfectly well ask for IPv6 address records via IPv4, or vice versa. (IPv4 "A" and IPv6 "AAAA" are just two possible data types alongside TXT, MX, SRV...)

Comment: They (ISP's tech support) said that they are still not using IPv6 (so I guess it is kind a half-assed rollout). Thanks.

Comment: @yZaph Maybe you can disable IPv6 in your router, or at least the Router Advertisements/DHCPv6.